# Restrict content access by term reference in profile

Tags: 7, users, taxonomy-terms

What I would like to accomplish is to have the following.  Please let me know if anyone is aware of modules that can accomplish this already or what direction I should take developmentally to accomplish this.  Thanks.

## Nodes

All nodes are tagged with terms from a particular vocab through the use of a taxonomy reference field.  The nodes are only accessible to specific users that have permissions to view the tagged terms.

## Taxonomy

I have one vocab that I am working with for all of this control and it is enabled for all content.

## Users

All users are tagged with terms from a particular vocab through the use of a taxonomy reference field added to their profiles.  This field should only be editable by a certain administrative roles.  Additionally, the user will only be able to access content on the site that is tagged with the terms set in this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I went with [Access by Terms module](http://drupal.org/project/abt) after finding that the [Term Access](http://drupal.org/project/term_access) module did not work for me.  Access by Terms also has permissions the make the field editable by certain roles in the profile and nodes, so that takes care of administration requirements too.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you can use [Term Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_access) module or its related modules.

From module's project page:

> ... controls node access based on taxonomy term fields. When the nodes taxonomy terms and the user taxonomy terms match, the user is awarded certain permissions.

Comment: This does deal with the issues surrounding user access to matching nodes.  It does however not cover dealing with the field level permissions that would be needed to keep users from editing the field on their profiles (this should be left to administrators [or really a set of roles]).  However, I have opened issue with the field permissions module to see if they will add field level permissions per entity.  If they don't I will code a custom module to handle the field level permissions per entity.  Awarding to you since the answer takes care of most of the difficulty.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually after testing that module I found that it "simply does nothing" after configuration.  I assume there is something busted in code as this is a pretty default install.  I switched to http://drupal.org/project/abt and everything seems to be working.  ABT seems to differ as described here: http://drupal.org/node/1498354 and it works.